# Have icons display in rows when on mobile device

Tags: html, css, sass

These icons are supposed to be in two rows of three on mobile, however they have ended up in one single column. How do I fix this problem?

HTML

```
    <div class="skill-section">
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="html.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="css.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="js.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="sass.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="react.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="skill-box"><img src="python.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.feature-box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    img{
        width: 150px;
        margin: 0 0 12px 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Media Query

```
/* Skills */
section .skill-section{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    .skill-box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 44%;
            img{
                width: 44%;
                padding: 10px;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using LESS or SASS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `section` before `.skill-section`, in your CSS.
Maybe this was your problem?

I added in a fiddle, a height and background.. to see the skill boxes.
It looks correct, if this is what you want to achieve:

[image]

Or maybe show some more code lines, for better help/information.

Answer (score -2):

```
/* Skills */
#skills{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    .feature-box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        img{
            width: 30px;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this the answer for your question? If yes, explain why your own code solves your own problem, if not, then delete this and add to your question instead of an answer